# Hibernate Search lock on writing makes querying slow

Tags: hibernate, lucene, load-balancing, hibernate-search

I am using hibernate search for a project, it is writing heavily to the DB and thus to the lucene index.

From time to time I experience that queries are too slow, that happens when the app is under heavy usage.

I was thinking in moving to a cluster configuration, and synchronizing every 10 minutes.

Based on your experience is this a good aproach? How long should I sync?

Comment: You should find out what the real bottleneck is before trying to optimize anything. Is it disk, CPU, excess of synchronization,...?

Comment: Please tag more carefully. You had tagged this as [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka: clustering, a data mining technique). You probably meant [tag:load-balancing].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided index and database updates are the real cause for the slowdown clustering can indeed be the solution. You will have to try and potentially profile more to get to the root of the problem.

Regarding the cluster configuration sync time. Let's start the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/) here first

> The recommended value for the refresh period is (at least) 50% higher
>   that the time to copy the information (default 3600 seconds - 60
>   minutes).

and

> If a copy is still in progress when the following refresh period
>   elapses, the second copy operation will be skipped.

So the question is, how big is your index and how long does it take to sync the index to the slave. Again, that is something you need to try. The other factor is how long you can/want to wait until a change is searchable. The refresh period is in this sense very application specific.